# "inzwischen" / "mittlerweile"

Tags: word-usage

Ich möchte wissen, ob die Verwendung von *inzwischen* und *mittlerweile* in den folgenden Sätze stimmt:

> 1a. Ich hatte dich lange nicht gesehen und inzwischen ist mein Deutsch viel besser geworden.
>   1b. Ich hatte dich lange nicht gesehen und mittlerweile ist mein Deutsch viel besser geworden.
>
> 2a. Ich muss noch arbeiten, du kannst inzwischen essen.
>   2b. Ich muss noch arbeiten, du kannst mittlerweile essen.
>
> 3a. Der Wettbewerb findet erst in zwei Jahren statt, inzwischen bereiten sie sich aber schon darauf vor.
>   3b. Der Wettbewerb findet erst in zwei Jahren statt, mittlerweile bereiten sie sich aber schon darauf vor.

Comment: One more good question about synonyms is closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alle Sätze sind grundsätzlich (grammatikalisch & semantisch) korrekt, 2b *wirkt* aber unsinnig; (3b auch ein bisschen.)   (Das hängt aber letztendlich vom Kontext ab.)

***mittlerweile*** bedeutet, dass ein neuer Zustand eingetreten ist; (schon vor dem Bezugszeitpunkt, der typischerweise die Gegenwart ist.)  Die Erreichung dieses Zustands hatte eine gewisse Zeit benötigt, z. B. zur Vorbereitung.

***inzwischen*** kann synonym zu *mittlerweile* gebraucht werden;  oder es bedeutet *während dieser Zeit*, *derweil*, *gleichzeitig* - während auf die Vollendung eines anderen Vorgangs gewartet wird, der Zeit braucht.  (Für *inzwischen* kann man oft auch *in der Zwischenzeit* einsetzen, welches auch beide Bedeutungen annehmen kann.)

1a & 1b sind synonym.  Bei 1a hat *inzwischen* die Bedeutung von *mittlerweile*.  (Übrigens: "habe" statt "hatte" wäre vielleicht besser.  Oder auch "Ich hatte Dich lange nicht gesehen und inzwischen *war* mein Deutsch viel besser geworden."  In diesem Fall wäre *mittlerweile* weniger geeignet, da es sich eher auf die Gegenwart bezieht (meinem Gefühl nach).)

2a stimmt, 2b ist wie gesagt unsinnig (augenscheinlich).

3a: *inzwischen* im Sinne von *derweil* / *während dieser Zeit*

3b: Wenn das eine Übungsaufgabe ist, ist diese Variante wohl eher als falsch gemeint.  Es wäre aber ein absolut stimmiger Satz, z. B. wenn der Wettbewerb bereits seit einem Jahr erwartet wird (also 3 Jahre im Voraus) und man noch nicht umgehend mit der Vorbereitung begonnen hatte.