# Unterschied zwischen „inzwischen“ und „mittlerweile“

Tags: difference, adverb

Welcher Unterschied besteht zwischen den Adverbien „inzwischen“ und „mittlerweile“?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9207/inzwischen-mittlerweile

Answer (score 4):

Keinen. *Inzwischen* und *mittlerweile* werden synonym verwendet. *Inzwischen* ist das übliche Adverb, *mittlerweile* nimmt man zur Abwechselung oder um Missverständnissen vorzubeugen.

Schlecht:

> **Inzwischen** haben **zwischen** Washington und Moskau wieder Gespräche stattgefunden.

Besser:

> Mittlerweile haben zwischen Washington und Moskau wieder Gespräche stattgefunden.